# Can Grails exceptionHandler support the following Error Handling Flow

Tags: grails, error-handling

In my rails app that I am porting to grails whenever an unexpected error occurs I intercept the error automatically and display a form to the user informing them that an error has occured and asking them for further information.  Meanwhile, as the form is rendered I write the stack trace and other information about who was logged in to a database table.  Then if the form is submitted I add that information to the error report.

I cannot tell from the exceptionHandler documentation and BootStrap examples whether that will allow me to grab all the information including various session and request parameters and then stuff them into a database and then post a form.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a controller to handle exceptions instead of directly going to error.gsp by changing the '500' code mapping in grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy from

```
"500"(view:'/error')
```

to

```
"500"(controller: 'errors', action: 'error')
```

Run 'grails create-controller errors' and add the 'error' action:

```
class ErrorsController {

   def error = {
      def exception = request['javax.servlet.error.exception']?.cause?.cause
      if (exception) {
         // handle exception
      }
   }
}
```

Since you're now in a controller you can access the request, etc. and do whatever database or other post-handling work you like.

Comment: Hello Burt,
It goes to the controller I want, but there are no params in the request that allow me to find the original error.  Does this work in grails 1.1.1?

Comment: Sorry, that was for 1.2. In 1.2 there's an extra wrapper around the execptions - in 1.1 there's just one wrapper. So remove the 2nd "?.cause" and it'll work in 1.1.